# QField Cloud logo not appearing

Tags: qgis, qfield, qgis-cloud, qfieldsync

I'm trying to work with QGis Field. I have successfully set an offline project up, but I have a problem with the cloud. The issue is that after installing the plugin, I do not see the cloud icon [as it in here](https://docs.qfield.org/get-started/tutorials/get-started-qfc/). Someone knows why?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed an old QFieldSync version. This might be because you are also using an old QGIS version, the oldest QGIS version supported is 3.16. Make sure that you have installed QFieldSync v4.1.0.

You should see something like this:
[image]